# iPad simulator font installation

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7.1, uifont

How can I know "Helvetica Neue Lt Std" font is installed in my ipad 7.1 simulator. If it is not installed , how can i install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code and see console while debug you will get all the font family which is there in your ipad

```
NSLog(@"%@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Helvetica LT"]);
```

if font is not there then you add font name in your plist file like displayed in attached screenshot and add font in your projects resource Directory
[image]

Comment: This will only print out to console. I think think want to check if it exists and if it doesn't install it. So where do you check if it exists and where do you install the font if it doesn't?

Comment: if font exist then it will display in console otherwise it will print nothing in console

Comment: Conclusion: 1) Can use the above NSLog.... to know whether a font exists 2) You cannot add a custom font to simulator 3) You can add a custom font via plist for the specific app like shown above.

Comment: Right so your code will check to see if it doesn't exist and if it doesn't it will install the font, bloody hell I didn't realize after all these years of programming in objective-c that `NSLog` acted like an `if statement`. I really thought it only printed to the console, but since it works like an `if statement` I should review my code and change some. If you can't tell I am being sarcastic, `NSLog` is not an `if statement` so I don't have a clue what you think it does do.

Answer (score 0):

You can not install custom front to iOS device or simulator. Please correct me if I am wrong.
But you can use [custom fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BiOS%5D%20custom%20font) in your app.